# How can I find the size of a type?

Tags: llvm

I'm holding a `Type*` in my hand. How do I find out its size (the size objects of this type will occupy in memory) in bits / bytes? I see all kinds of methods allowing me to get "primitive" or "scalar" size, but that won't help me with aggregate types...

Comment: you can use LLVM API <https://llvm.org/doxygen/Constants_8cpp_source.html#l02379> now.It is implemented use the getelementptr.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The size depends on the target (for several reasons, alignment being one of them).

In LLVM versions 3.2 and above, you need to use [DataLayout](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html), in particular its `getTypeAllocSize` method. This returns the size in bytes, there's also a bit version named `getTypeAllocSizeInBits`. A `DataLayout` instance can be obtained by creating it from the current module: `DataLayout* TD = new DataLayout(M)`.

With LLVM up to version 3.1 (including), use `TargetData` instead of `DataLayout`. It exposes the same `getTypeAllocSize` methods, though.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to retreive the DataLayout?
e.g. how to get that Module?
I initially tried to get to the ASTContext, since it provides a getTypeSize method but also there I have no idea on how to retreive the ASTContext from lets say a FieldDecl* ... Same with DataLayout as a beginner I dont really have any insight on how to get the things that provide useful functionality :/
note: decls have getASTContext method but apparently it is a deleted function... *sigh*

Comment: @Julian ASTContext is a Clang construct, not a core LLVM one. I suggest asking a separate question about finding out the size of a type in Clang.

Comment: And how does one convert `TypeSize` to `Value`?

Comment: Apparently you do `llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(context), module->getDataLayout().getTypeAllocSize(fooType))`

Answer (score 37):

If you *only* need the size because you are inserting it into the IR (e.g., so you can send it to a call to `malloc()`), you can use the `getelementptr` instruction to do the dirty work (with a little casting), as [described here](http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/SizeOf-OffsetOf-VariableSizedStructs.txt) (with updating for modern LLVM):

> Though LLVM does not contain a special purpose `sizeof`/`offsetof` instruction, the
>   `getelementptr` instruction can be used to evaluate these values.  The basic idea
>   is to use `getelementptr` from the `null` pointer to compute the value as desired.
>   Because `getelementptr` produces the value as a pointer, the result is casted to
>   an integer before use.
>
> For example, to get the size of some type, `%T`, we would use something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> %Size = getelementptr %T* null, i32 1
> %SizeI = ptrtoint %T* %Size to i32
> ```
>
> This code is effectively pretending that there is an array of `T` elements,
>   starting at the `null` pointer.  This gets a pointer to the 2nd `T` element
>   (element #1) in the array and treats it as an integer.  This computes the 
>   size of one `T` element.

The good thing about doing this is that it is useful in exactly the cases where you do not care what the value is; where you just need to pass the correct value from the IR to something. That's by far the most common case for my need for `sizeof()`-alike operations in the IR generation.

---

The page also goes on to describe how to do an `offsetof()` equivalent:

> To get the offset of some field in a structure, a similar trick is used.  For
>   example, to get the address of the 2nd element (element #1) of `{ i8, i32* }` 
>   (which depends on the target alignment requirement for pointers), something 
>   like this should be used:
>
> ```
> %Offset = getelementptr {i8,i32*}* null, i32 0, i32 1
> %OffsetI = ptrtoint i32** %Offset to i32
> ```
>
> This works the same way as the `sizeof` trick: we pretend there is an instance of
>   the type at the `null` pointer and get the address of the field we are interested
>   in.  This address is the offset of the field.
>
> Note that in both of these cases, the expression will be evaluated to a
>   constant at code generation time, so there is no runtime overhead to using this
>   technique.

The IR optimizer also converts the values to constants.

Comment: I've only done this answer because I've had problems accessing the content at that page, and this stuff is _useful_. I had to scrape it out of the Google cache (and correct for a few years of drift)…

Comment: For this to work I still need to hard-code the size of a pointer, as that is the number of bits I convert to, right?