# Would size of any type always be multple of its aligment?

Tags: alignment, size, llvm, sizeof, memory-alignment

I haven't found a clear statement in documents but I found it's awalys true in my experimentals, that

```
bits_of(A) % alignment(A) == 0
```

In fact, if it's not true, some padding is required between elements in array of that type, so I believe it must be true but I just want to make sure here.

---

I'm thinking another question, what is the size of a type?

Actually, the LLVM IR doesn't provide any standard instruction to get the size of a type but only by some trick like `(int)(((T*) NULL) + 1)`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608250/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-type) and [there](http://nondot.org/sabre/LLVMNotes/SizeOf-OffsetOf-VariableSizedStructs.txt).

However, it's only the difference of aligned adjacent pointers, which is always multiple of its alignment.
And it may not be the *actually occupied* size.
For example, the structure `{i8, i32, i8}`, has 12bytes in adjacent aligned pointers, but only occupies 9bytes considered fields alignment (9bytes is enough for memory allocation)

```
i8 | 3bytes padding | i32 | i8
```

Then which size is the size? Is *size* a controversial concept in different situations and languages?

Comment: I'm also interested in other situation outside LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM permits you to configure alignment in a Module using a [data layout](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html). Most data layouts will be as you've seen, but that's not required by LLVM. You can make a module where an int type has 256-bit alignment and 32-bit size, or 32-bit alignment and 256-bit size, and both of those make sense in some situations (consider a 32-bit addressable system with 256-bit L1 cache lines).

I don't want to go into your size question; size is such a pain. IMO the answer to "what's the size of …" varies with the reason for the question, but that's very much IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It's the distinguishment between [`StoreSize`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#acfcd22eb38dbfe1acbf138754297437a) and [`AllocSize`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#aa48b3b7e554b44f4e513d5dd8d9f9343),

here examples from [LLVM source](https://llvm.org/doxygen/DataLayout_8h_source.html)

```
/// Size examples:
   ///
   /// Type        SizeInBits  StoreSizeInBits  AllocSizeInBits[*]
   /// ----        ----------  ---------------  ---------------
   ///  i1            1           8                8
   ///  i8            8           8                8
   ///  i19          19          24               32
   ///  i32          32          32               32
   ///  i100        100         104              128
   ///  i128        128         128              128
   ///  Float        32          32               32
   ///  Double       64          64               64
   ///  X86_FP80     80          80               96
   ///
   /// [*] The alloc size depends on the alignment, and thus on the target.
   ///     These values are for x86-32 linux.
```

The `AllocSize` defined as *the offset in bytes between successive objects* is alway multiple of alignments of course, but the `StoreSize`, defined as *the maximum number of bytes that may be overwritten by storing*, may not.