# LLVM : Store Values of all types inside an i8 array at compile time

Tags: llvm

An example of the title would be storing a symbol (e.g. a function pointer) inside the array next to, let's say, integers. This would allow the linker to place the right address of the symbols, which we do not know at optimization-time, in the `i8` array.

How can I store any LLVM Value, whichever it's type is (as long as it's sized), inside an `[<Sum of sizes> x i8]` array ? This, storing Values of any type inside an `[N x i8]` array, would take place in a LLVM pass.
I am aware that it will require to change every use of these values by a pointer cast and a load; this isn't an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow what you're trying to do with the i8 array, but I assume this is the core of your question:

> How can I store any LLVM Value, whichever it's type is (as long as
> it's sized), inside an [ x i8] array

To reinterpret an LLVM value as one with a different type, use [bitcast](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction). You could obtain a pointer to your data and then bitcast it to i8*, then use [llvm.memcpy](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-memcpy-intrinsic) to write it to your array. For obtaining the runtime size of a type, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608250/how-can-i-find-the-size-of-a-type).

Alternatively you could put all your objects in a giant struct, and then bitcast it to an i8 array where it is needed. This is probably preferable as it would more naturally compile to something that has no runtime overhead.